# Bootstrap's pull-right is not cleared or reset

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was working on a sample where I had to align a button group to the right.
I found the css class `.pull-right`.
While it correctly moved the button group, I was unable to reset the next section.
I've used the clearfix mixin on several objects, I cannot clear the way `section` intersects with the button group.

The sample on bootply (link below):

```
<div class="container foo">
   <div class="btn-group pull-right" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
      </div>
  <section class="debug text-center">
    <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
    <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

And the css

```
.foo
{
  .clearfix();
}

.foo::before,
.foo::after {
    content: " "; // 1
    display: table; // 2
}
.foo::after {
  clear: both;
}
```

Due to missing less mixin support I manually implemented the mixin

Here is a runnable example: http://www.bootply.com/8GgDsWc8kZ

I've been googling this and I put foo into every div there, no place cleared the section from intersecting.

Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be missing some tags. That's what's causing Bootstrap to not function the way you expect.

**[BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/Z0CO9rbSjj)**

```
    <div class="container foo">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 pull-right">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <section class="debug text-center row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
                <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

I'd suggest that you take some time to read over the [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) documentation on the Bootstrap website.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a div between the buttons and the box with the `clearfix` class from Bootstrap applied to it.

[**BOOTPLY**](http://www.bootply.com/9RKNSRIkBr)

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container foo">
   <div class="btn-group pull-right" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
      </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <section class="debug text-center">
    <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
    <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, I added a boostrap "row" and "col-xs-12" around your 3 buttons, as well as around your section.

```
<div class="container foo">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
   <div class="btn-group pull-right" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
  <section class="debug text-center">
    <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
    <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
  </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/0TSYSI4T8b